# Tkinter animation - simulate an analogue clock

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I currently have built the clock and hour, minute, and second hand using Tkinter.

```py
hour_num = [3, 2, 1, 12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]

for i in hour_num:
    text_x = ORIGIN[0] + clock_radius * math.cos(theta)
    text_y = ORIGIN[1] - clock_radius * math.sin(theta)
    theta += d_theta
    screen.create_text(text_x, text_y, text=i, font="Arial 25", fill="white")

## Time info
hour = datetime.now().hour
minute = datetime.now().minute
second = datetime.now().second

secondhand = screen.create_line(ORIGIN[0], ORIGIN[1], ORIGIN[0], ORIGIN[1] - clock_radius + 50, width=13, fill="blue")
minutehand = screen.create_line(ORIGIN[0], ORIGIN[1], ORIGIN[0], ORIGIN[1] - clock_radius + 70, width=13, fill="green")
hourhand = screen.create_line(ORIGIN[0], ORIGIN[1], ORIGIN[0], ORIGIN[1] - clock_radius + 90, width=13, fill="red")
```

So right now the canvas looks like this:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/A8BpW.png)

Can someone help me animate the clock hands with the current time?

I have tried using trigonometry, to find the distance between each hour (Take the cosine ratio of the angle from the origin). First, I realized it is not perfect right-triangle, and second of all. The hour hand will not be realistic: 2:50's hour hand will be closer to 3 than to 2.

Thanks

Comment: You can use both hour and minute to calculate the angle of the hour hand.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a snippet of code from a clock I wrote a few years ago.

```
def getHMS():
    time = datetime.now()
    h,m,s = time.hour, time.minute, time.second
    return h,m,s

def updateClock():
    h,m,s = getHMS()
    ac = -90    # Correction angle since 0degrees should be at the top
    ha = (((h%12)+(m/60))/12)*360 + ac
    ma = ((m + (s/60)) / 60 )*360 + ac
    sa = ((s / 60) * 360) + ac
    moveHand(hour_hand, ha)
    moveHand(minute_hand, ma)
    moveHand(second_hand, sa)
    canvas.after(1000,updateClock)
```

Inside the updateClock method, note that in order to figure out the angle of the hour hand `ha`, I use both the hours `h` and the minutes `m` values. Similar for the minutes hand, I use both the minutes and seconds values to set the angle.

EDIT: Some extra help with drawing hands

First you need to draw a hand (doesn't matter where it is drawn really)

```
hour_hand_line = canvas.create_line(250,250,350,250, fill="purple")
```

Then you need to move that hand based on the current time using the angle we calculates

```
def moveHourHand(angle):
    hour_length = 150
    #Centre position of hand
    x1 = 250 
    y1 = 250
    #End Postition of hand
    x2 = x1 + hour_length * math.cos(math.radians(angle))
    y2 = y1 + hour_length * math.sin(math.radians(angle))
    #Move existing line to new position
    canvas.coords(hour_hand_line, x1,y1,x2,y2)
```

The start position `x1` and `y1` are the centre of the clock, the end position of the line `x2` and `y2` are based on the length of the line with some adjustment based on trigonometry. We then just move the line to that position.

Comment: Can you give me more hint on moveHand() function? How do I adjust the coordinates so it matches the angle?

Comment: @ENG2D Some additional help provided. You'll need to do some work to get it all going together but the complex parts are there for you to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I didn't expect a full answer, a hint would be helpful enough! Thank you so much!